# Calling Enums from another project does not appear inside of p:selectOneRadio

Tags: maven, primefaces, enums

I have a java application project, I use it as a core library. Inside, I have some models and EnumBean class which has enums. I added this jar to a maven web project. Everything seems good but when I run web application, in a page selectOneRadio button doesn't show enum values. So selectOneRadio comes with empty

But before this when enumbean class was in a web project, everthing was good. When I carry them to the library, ıt doesn't give error, but doesn't show enums in a page.

Can you help me?

Code :

***In different project I have EnumBean class ..***

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class EnumBean {

    public enum State {
        @SerializedName("0")
        PASSIVE("Passive"),
        @SerializedName("1")
        ACTIVE("Active");

        private final String name;

        private State(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }
    }

    public State[] getStateValues() {
        return State.values();
    }
}
```

***And inside of another project..***

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        Hello from Facelets
        <h:form>
            <br/>
            <br/>

            <p:selectOneMenu id="xyz" value="#{welcomeView.selectedState}" style="width:125px">
                <f:selectItems  value="#{enumBean.stateValues}" var="stateValue" itemLabel="#{stateValue.name}" itemValue="#{stateValue}" />
                <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{welcomeView.someFunc()}"/>
                <p:ajax update="xyz"/>
            </p:selectOneMenu>

            <br/>
            <br/>


            <p:outputLabel for="stateTry" value="State :"/> 
            <p:selectOneRadio id="stateTry" value="#{welcomeView.selectedState2}" layout="grid" columns="1" >
                <f:selectItems value="#{enumBean.stateValues}" var="stateValue" itemLabel="#{stateValue.name}" itemValue="#{stateValue}" />
            </p:selectOneRadio>

        </h:form>

    </h:body>
</html>

package view;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class WelcomeView implements Serializable {

    private EnumBean.State selectedState;
    private EnumBean.State selectedState2;

//Some Getter Setter..



    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

    }

    public void someFunc(final AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {

        System.out.println("------");
        if (selectedState.ordinal() == EnumBean.State.ACTIVE.ordinal()) {
            System.out.println("active");
        }  else {
            System.out.println("passive");
        }
    }

//Some functions

}
```

Thanks..

Comment: So if you don't use maven but copy the dependent project manually into the WEB-INF/lib folder it works? Or of you replace the enum with static strings?

Comment: @Kukeltje I tried adding into the lib folder in another non maven project bu it was same.. I can't replace with strings..

Comment: 1: then it is not maven related. 2: so `@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class EnumBean {

    public static String getPassive() { return "passive" }` etc... works? That would be strange